# Parse.com - How to login as a user without knowing their password?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com, and like it a lot.

I'd like users of my app to automatically be assigned an account (which I create behind the scenes using the Parse API) and then log them into their account.

I could easily do this if I assigned them a hard coded, standard password for their account, e.g superPass123.

Is this the only way I can do this? Or is there some other way to allow me to login automatically as a user without knowing a users password, if my user has "super" rights?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you secure it enough, you can essentially do this by using Cloud Code.  I'll skip over the validation/authorization part, and focus on how.

A cloud function, which, running with the Master Key, can query for a user.  The cloud function returns the users session token to the client (user.getSessionToken()), which uses the "become" functionality to log in as that user.

Relevant posts:

Announcing the "become" feature: http://blog.parse.com/2013/12/03/bring-your-own-login/

Tutorial that covers an implementation of cloud code providing a session token: https://parse.com/tutorials/adding-third-party-authentication-to-your-web-app

Comment: Hello, I'm currently facing a similar issue related to third party identity provider sign ins (especially Google+). [Here is my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28114422/how-to-link-google-signed-in-users-on-parse-backend-on-android) about how to create users on Parse after Google+ sign in on Client. Should I follow [this blogpost](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) and log in users from backend as well, then use the become method. This is a bit hazy to me, can you please tell me the process in brief. Thanks!