# How to create a parse _User account from a Android Google token?

Tags: android, parse-platform, oauth-2.0

I've found some fragments of useful information.

http://blog.parse.com/announcements/bring-your-own-login/ shows me how to login an Android app *once* I have a Parse token.

I can successfully obtain a Google token for a phone's Google account.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth

```
/**
 * Gets an authentication token from Google and handles any
 * GoogleAuthException that may occur.
 */
protected String fetchToken() throws IOException {
    try {
        return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope);
    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userRecoverableException) {
        // GooglePlayServices.apk is either old, disabled, or not present
        // so we need to show the user some UI in the activity to recover.
        mActivity.handleGoogleException(userRecoverableException);
    } catch (GoogleAuthException fatalException) {
        // Some other type of unrecoverable exception has occurred.
        // Report and log the error as appropriate for your app.
    }
    return null;
}
```

How can get Parse to use a Google token to create a Parse token?

I assume that this will involve writing some Cloud Code, but I'm not clear on what that Cloud Code should do.  I think it needs to create or find a new _User for the Google token and return the Parse token.

Are there any Parse Cloud Code examples of how to handle Google Android login/signup, or examples of anything other than Faceboook/Twitter?

Comment: You want to create a new account using email retrieve from Google Auth?

Comment: @Ralphilius I want to create a new Parse _User, from one of the Google accounts that is setup on an Android phone.  I already have code working which gives me a token for the Google account (that the user chooses, if there is more than one on  their phone).  I can also get the email address of the account.  My issues are all Parse-side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note: This answer does not apply to the Open Source Parse Server, as it uses revocable sessions only. Check out [parse-server/issues/1392](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1392) for further update

**Update (Jan-2016):**

You need to turn off [Revocable Session](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/announcing-new-enhanced-sessions/) in order to call `getSessionToken` on `Parse.User`. Go to **App Settings** >> **Users** >> Turn off **Require revocable sessions**. This is not new in 2016, but at the time of giving answer, the author did not know of this change.

---

I will break into 2 cases for easier to follow: New User and Returning User.

### 1. New User

The flow is as below:

1. User authorizes and a token is acquired
2. We create a new user with a random password

You can create a ParseUser using following code inside the `newChooseAccountIntent()` method that return email.

```
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
user.setUsername(mEmail);
user.setPassword(randomPassword);
user.setEmail(mEmail);
user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
  public void done(ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
    } else {
      // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
      // to figure out what went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

### 2. Returning User

This is the where most of people stuck, as I researched over the Internet. The flow is as below:

1. User authorizes and the app gets a token
2. We pass this token to Cloud Code to validate. We need to check if this token is signed by Google and if it is meant for us ([android-developers](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) (2013)).
3. After you can verify that the token is valid, you can query for the user in Cloud Code using `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` method and return the session key by using `getSessionToken()` method on the query result.
4. Use the session key to save login state on disk by calling `becomeInBackground` method

**To validate the token**, you can send `Parse.Cloud.httprequest` to this endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=`. This is instructed in [Google Identity Documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth). You will receive data as below:

```
{
 "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
 "sub": "110169484474386276334",
 "azp": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "email": "billd1600@gmail.com",
 "at_hash": "X_B3Z3Fi4udZ2mf75RWo3w",
 "email_verified": "true",
 "aud": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "iat": "1433978353",
 "exp": "1433981953"
}
```

Things need to compare are "aud", "azp" and "email" which are translated as audience, authorized party and email.

**To query for the current user on Cloud Code**:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("email",mEmail);
query.first({
  success: function(user) {
    // Use user..getSessionToken() to get a session token
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    //
  },
  useMasterKey: true
});
```

**Note:** Make sure you have following scope so that the email will show up when you check on Cloud Code: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read`

Comment: If I use a random password, how does the user sign in next time?  Possibly from the same app on a *different* device with the same google account, so storing it locally is not a solution.

Comment: Hello, I have got a new solution. It will not be easy to implement though.

Comment: For Google you need to obtain the token with `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken`, send it to the Cloud Code function, and control it by sending a POST request to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token` with the following body params: `code` which is the token, `grant_type` which needs to be equal to "authorization_code", `client_id` and `client_secret` which are your client information. If the token is valid, you will get an access token, refresh token and an expiration date.

Comment: Updated with token validation method

Comment: Google do not recommend setting the email as a user name since the email can change. Better set the userId as user name, and then create your own column for displayName where you may set the users full name or email.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fVLQr302, here is a complete working parse cloud code snippet i created following up the instruction here. http://pastebin.com/133LVYbm, ios client code using the same. Might help somebody linking up all the pieces.

Comment: I am able to find the user using email but user.getSessionToken() is not returning session

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Get the Google token
2. Send the Google token to your Parse back-end to validate
3. Use the validated Google token to create a Parse session token
4. Use the Parse session token to allow users to access the app

---

**(1):** See the guide: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

---

**(2):** Send the ID token to your back-end server (in this case Parse).

```
//sending the token to the backend
        String backendApiUrlToGenerateSessionToken = your_url_with_cloud_code_to_generate_session_token;
        Log.i("URL: ", backendApiUrlToGenerateSessionToken);

        RequestQueue newRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JSONObject getSessionTokenJsonRequestBody = new JSONObject();
        //back-end requires the token and Google client ID to be verified
        try {
            getSessionTokenJsonRequestBody.put("idToken", idTokenFromGoogle);
            getSessionTokenJsonRequestBody.put("GClientId", your_google_client_id);     //find it in google-services.json file
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final String requestBody = getSessionTokenJsonRequestBody.toString();

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, backendApiUrlToGenerateSessionToken, getSessionTokenJsonRequestBody,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        //success callback
                        //set current user and continue
                        try {
                            ParseUser.becomeInBackground(response.getString("result"), new LogInCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                                    if (user != null){
                                        //successfully logged in, take the user to the last page they were on
                                        finish();
                                    }else{
                                        //error
                                        Log.e("Login error: ", e.getMessage());
                                        //show error dialog, prompt user to login again

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //error callback
                        int  statusCode = error.networkResponse.statusCode;
                        NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;

                        Log.d("Error Response req: ","" + statusCode + " " + response.data.toString());

                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders(){
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                //post parameters
                headers.put("X-Parse-Application-Id", getResources().getString(R.string.parse_app_id));
                headers.put("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", getResources().getString(R.string.parse_rest_api_key));
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody(){
                try {
                    String body;
                    if (requestBody == null) body = null;
                    else body = String.valueOf(requestBody.getBytes("utf-8"));
                    return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };
        newRequestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

---

**(3):** We've sent the token to our back-end, now we need to validate the token and generate our Parse session token in our back-end. Credit to @Amit http://pastebin.com/133LVYbm included logic to handle logged out users and subsequent login from the same Google account

```
//generating a random password
function getRandomString(){
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZ";
    var string_length = 10;
    var randomstring = '';

    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum + 1);
    }
    return randomstring;
}

Parse.Cloud.define("getSessionToken", function(request, response) {
    console.log(request);
    console.log(request.params.accessToken);
    console.log(request.params.GClientId);
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

//Verifying token (id Token)
var authTokenVerificationURL = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=" + request.params.idToken;
console.log(authTokenVerificationURL);
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url:authTokenVerificationURL
}).then(function(httpResponse){
    //Success
    //console.log("success httpResponse: " + httpResponse.text);

    //Verify if token is generated from our client
    var gAudience = httpResponse.data.aud;
    if(gAudience == request.params.GClientId) {
        console.log("Verified: Token is generated from our app");

        var user_emailId = httpResponse.data.email; 
        var user_username = httpResponse.data.name;
        //console.log(user_emailId);

        /*
        * 1. User signing up for the first time
        * 2. User already signed up logging in
        */

        //Check if User account exists for the emailId
        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        query.equalTo("email",user_emailId);
        query.first({
            success: function(user) {

                //if the user exists, they could have logged out so no sessionToken is available so we'll need to log them in again
                if(user) {
                    console.log("User found with Username: " + user.getUsername() + ", objectId: " + user.id);

                    //Generate the Session Token
                    var sessionToken = user.getSessionToken();
                    if(sessionToken) {
                        console.log("SessionToken: " + sessionToken);
                        response.success(sessionToken);
                    }else {
                        //create a new session - login (user can signup then log-out which deletes the session)
                        var newRandomPassword = getRandomString();
                        user.set("password", newRandomPassword);
                        user.save(null, {useMasterKey : true}).then(function(user){
                            Parse.User.logIn(user.get("username"), newRandomPassword).then(function(user){
                                var sessionToken = user.getSessionToken();
                                response.success(sessionToken);
                            }, function(error){
                                response.error("Cannot create session");
                            })
                        }, function(error){
                            response.error("Unable to save user data");
                        });

                    }

                }else {
                    console.log("User not found, Creating new account for user with emailId: " + user_emailId);

                    //Create New Account
                    var nUser = new Parse.User();
                    nUser.set("username",user_username);
                    nUser.set("password",getRandomString());
                    nUser.set("email",user_emailId);
                    nUser.signUp(null,{
                        success: function(user) {
                            console.log("New account created for user with emailID: " + user_emailId);

                            //Generate the Session Token
                            var sessionToken = user.getSessionToken();
                            console.log("SessionToken: " + sessionToken);
                            response.success(sessionToken);
                        },
                        error: function(user, error) {
                            console.log("Failed to create a new account for emailID: " + user_emailId);
                            console.log("User: " + user + ", Error: " + error);
                            response.error(error);
                        }
                    });
                }


            },
            error: function(user, error) {
                console.log("Query to fetch user failed");
                console.log("User: " + user + ", Error: " + error);;

                response.error(error);  
            },
            userMasterKey:true
        });



    }else { //Client has not login from our app
        console.log("Google AudienceID: " + gAudience + "\n AppClientId: " + request.params.GClientId);
        response.error('Invalid Audience');
    }

},function(httpResponse) {
    //Error
    console.log("Failed httpResponse: " + httpResponse.text);
    console.error('Request Failed with response code' + httpResponse.status);
    response.error('Failed to verify access token');
});

});
```

---

**(4)** Logic is in step **(2)** when the requestQueue returns the response we call the **becomenbackground()** method which saves the session and allows us to get the currently logged in user