# Android: Google Sign in Integration with Sashido (Parse.com SDK) without Cloud Code

Tags: java, android, google-signin

I'm writing this question and answer because I haven't seen a full solution to the integration of Google sign in on Android using Facebook's Parse SDK (or Sashido in my case) as a back-end *without cloud code*.

Related Questions:

- [How to link Google + signed in users on Parse backend on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28114422/how-to-link-google-signed-in-users-on-parse-backend-on-android)
- [Google Plus Login issues - Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/questions/google-plus-login-support-or-examples)

---

How would one go about integrating Google Sign in with Parse back-end without Cloud Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, follow the steps provided by Android Developers on starting and implementing the integration.

1. [Start Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)
2. [Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in)
3. In the `onCreate` your activity you need to build the [GoogleSignInOptions](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInOptions)

   ```
   GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
           .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
           .requestEmail()
           .build();
   ```

You can get your `web_client_id` when you add Google Services to your project to your Google Developers account. Find out more at: [Creating a Google API Console project and client ID](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project)

4. Build your [GoogleApiClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient) (make it a global instance `private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;`)

   ```
   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
           .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
               @Override
               public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                   Log.e("Failed", "failed" + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
               }
           })
           .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
           .build();
   ```
5. Listen out for the click on the dedicated button for your Google sign in and then start a `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignIntent(mGoogleApiClient);`

   `case R.id.btn_google:
      Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
      startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
      break;`

Make sure you've assigned a value to `RC_SIGN_IN` (I've done 1000)

6. Now start adding implementation to your `onActivityResult` method

   ```
   // Result returned from launching the Intent from
   //   GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
   if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
       GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
       handleSignInResult(result);
   } else {
       ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   }
   ```

Now to handle the sign in request:

```
`private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.e("handleSignIn", "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            final GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            if (acct != null) {
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
                query.setLimit(10000);
                query.whereEqualTo("email", acct.getEmail());
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            if (objects.size() == 0) {
                                saveNewUserGoogle(acct);
                            } else {
                                loginGoogleUser(objects.get(0), acct);
                            }
                        } else {
                            saveNewUserGoogle(acct);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("failed", "failed to sign in");
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        }
    }`
```

So what this method does is if the request to the GoogleSignIn Request is successful, get the account details, query the _User table in your database and to see if the email with the account matches. If it does, Log the user in.

`private void loginGoogleUser(ParseObject j, GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
           ParseUser.logInInBackground(j.getString("username"), String.valueOf(acct.getId()), new LogInCallback() {
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(AllLoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Log.e("failed", "could not be validated");
                    }
                }
            });
        }`

else sign the user up:

```
private void saveNewUserGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        google = true;
        final ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
        String mFullName = acct.getDisplayName();
        String mEmail = acct.getEmail();
        String mProfilePic = String.valueOf(acct.getPhotoUrl());
        String mUsername = acct.getId();
        String password = acct.getId();
        user.setUsername(mUsername);
        user.setEmail(mEmail);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.put("userEmail", mEmail);
        user.put("uniqueID", mUsername);
        user.put("name", mFullName);
        user.put("loginMethod", "Google");
        user.put("profilePicture", mProfilePic);
        user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Log.e("SaveTest", "Successful");
                        //sign user up
                    } else {
                        switch (e.getCode()) {
                            case ParseException.USERNAME_TAKEN:
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry, this username has already been taken.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case ParseException.USERNAME_MISSING:
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry, a username is needed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case ParseException.PASSWORD_MISSING:
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry, a password is needed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case ParseException.OBJECT_NOT_FOUND:
                                Toast.makeText(context, "invalid credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case ParseException.CONNECTION_FAILED:
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry, internet is needed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            default:
                                Log.d("Testing", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

    }
```

So for this if you set the password on Parse as the `clientID` it'll be unique to that user and can be read by Parse and given by Google.

**Note**: I'm setting the username as the Google Identifier and then when they have successfully connected and signed up I display a username dialog box where they enter a username, so it can be displayed as something in plain text rather than numerics.